# Parse JSON string that has \n\t\r

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm using requests library to fetch some data from an API call, however it keeps giving me bad JSON format. However when I do `json.loads()`, it's clean in my console window, when I save the thing it has `\r\t\n` in a file.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Referer': 'https://webapps.illinois.gov/IWCC/CaseDocket/CaseSearch/ResBirthEnquiry?Name=ILLINOIS%20STATE%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20&type=R&caseDet=19_004185',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}
params = (
    ('Name', 'ILLINOIS STATE                '),
    ('type', 'R'),
    ('_', '1601313293712'),
)
response = requests.get('https://webapps.illinois.gov/IWCC/CaseDocket/CaseSearch/GetBirthInquiryDetails', headers=headers, params=params).json()
with open('casedockets.json','w') as outfile:
    json.dump(response, outfile, indent=4)
```

it produces the following output:

```
"\"{\\r\\n\\\"nameBirthDetails\\\":\\r\\n{\\\"nameBirth10\\\":{\\r\\n\\t   \\\"petName\\\":\\\"MAURO, SEBASTIANO             \\\", \\r\\n\\t   \\\"respName\\\":\\\"ILLINOIS STATE                \\\", \\r\\n\\t   \\\"injuryDate\\\":\\\"11/21/2002\\\",\\r\\n\\t   \\\"caseYear\\\":\\\"03\\\", \\r\\n\\t   \\\"caseType\\\":\\\"WC\\\", \\r\\n\\t   \\\"caseSeqNbr\\\":\\\"003884\\\", \\r\\n\\t   \\\"dateFiled\\\":\\\"01/24/2003\\\", \\r\\n\\t   \\\"petBirthDate\\\":\\\"03/13/1943\\\", \\r\\n\\t
```

^ That is just the chunk of the JSON data...how can I make this a valid JSON so I can extract the keys I need?

Comment: Why wouldn’t you try a global replace of \t with a space character?

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) Debugging clearly shows `response` is not already `dict` but in fact a `str` that you need to `json.loads` on to get a `dict`

Comment: Curiously, this doesn't seem to be the fault of the OP. Having actually read the code that was written, the OP is _already_ converting the response to json using the `.json()` transform on the response object. An _extra_ json parse is required to get the data, something that arguably the server is doing incorrectly.

Comment: @Stephen Thanks!!!! After reviewing your comment, I had to do json.loads() one more again after already parsing it once.

Comment: @newb12431 that is totally a bug int he API. They are serializing a JSON string. When you deserialize it, you get a string, that string is a valid JSON. Someone on their end is double-serializing.  Yes, you can fix this by deserializing twice, but it's definitely a bug on their end

Answer (score 1):

This web server is busted and must be blamed. It serialized a JSON object and then serialized it again, perhaps with a second json.dumps or maybe a python str or repr of the string - they are close enough, its hard to tell. When you did `.json()` you ended up with the original json serialized string. Your `json.dump` just did the double serialization again.

You can fix the problem by adding a second `json.loads` before the dump. If the server is ever fixed, that step will fail, and you'll know you need to update your code... so add exception handling.

```
import requests, json

headers = {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
        'Referer': 'https://webapps.illinois.gov/IWCC/CaseDocket/CaseSearch/ResBirthEnquiry?Name=ILLINOIS%20STATE%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20&type=R&caseDet=19_004185',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}
params = (
    ('Name', 'ILLINOIS STATE                '),
    ('type', 'R'),
    ('_', '1601313293712'),
)
response = requests.get('https://webapps.illinois.gov/IWCC/CaseDocket/CaseSearch/GetBirthInquiryDetails',
    headers=headers, params=params)
try:
    # buggy server returns doubly encoded json - until maybe someday it doesn't
    data = response.json()
    data = json.loads(data)
except TypeError:
    print("Looks like buggy server is no longer double encoded")
with open('casedockets.json','w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>The server is not to blame.</s> Edit: Apparently the server *is* (also) to blame. Leaving this answer up because of the comment thread.

`requests` doesn't parse the JSON for you, so by using `json.dump` you're encoding the encoded JSON again as a JSON string.

Simply do `outfile.write(response.read())` to write the actual, unmodified response body from the server into the file.

To parse the JSON and get a Python object out of it, use `response.json()`.

Comment: I think some wires might be crossed here because the OP's data output doesn't align with what their code produces. The output snippet posted appears to be the unparsed response, but the code they provided already uses the `.json()` transformation method.

Comment: Hey @Thomas, when I directly do json.dump(response.json()) into a file, it still has  data like this "{\r\n\"nameBirthDetails\":\r\n{\"nameBirth10\":{\r\n\t   \"petName\":\"MAURO, SEBASTIANO             \", \r\n\t   \"respName\":\"ILLINOIS STATE                \", \r\n\t   \"injuryDate\":\"11/21/2002\",\r\n\t

Comment: @Stephen the response of the request already seems to be stringified json inside a string. `r.content[0:100]` is `b'"{\\r\\n\\"nameBirthDetails\\":\...`, where the outermost `'` denotes the start of the string, and the contents of the string is another string (inside `"...`) that contains the stringified json.

Comment: So I'd say the server _is_ to blame -- IDK why it returns a json that contains a string that has the actual json response. Doing `json.loads(requests.get(...).json())` works fine and converts the response to an actual usable `dict`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi my thoughts exactly, see my comment on the OP!

Comment: Yup Stephen, I had to do json.loads once again, it was the server issue. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is from the way the server is returning the content of the request. An initial parse of the data using the `.json` transform yields a string-encoded json structure. Using the `json.loads` function on it will yield the actual json data. The first `.json` call interprets the entire string as a json string, and by spec, returns that. Then the next call takes the now object-bound json string and interprets that as the correct json object.

Ultimately, you'll need to do both json parses every time or contact the server admin and tell them that they have a flawed web API.

The solution:
`json.dump(json.loads(response))`